# Db2: How to deploy an Oracle PL/SQL package in db2?

Tags: sql, plsql, db2, plsql-package

I tried to create an Oracle PL/SQL package in Db2, but ran into errors.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ARITHMETIC AS
       function add (
          first number,
          second number)
       return number;
    END ARITHMETIC;


    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ARITHMETIC AS
      function add(
          first number,
          second number)
       return number AS

      BEGIN
       return first + second;
      END add;
    END ARITHMETIC;
```

When I run the above code, it results in the following error:

> Deploy [tnbdr]DB2INST1.ARITHMETIC  Running
>        DB2INST1.ARITHMETIC - Deploy for debug started.
>        Create PL/SQL Package Specification returns SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601.
>        DB2INST1.ARITHMETIC: 1: An unexpected token "PACKAGE" was found 
>   following "CREATE OR REPLACE ".  Expected tokens may include:
>
> "VIEW".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.18.60
>       An unexpected token "PACKAGE" was found following "CREATE OR REPLACE ".  Expected tokens may include:  "VIEW".. SQLCODE=-104,
>   SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.18.60
>       DB2INST1.ARITHMETIC - Deploy for debug failed.
>       DB2INST1.ARITHMETIC - Roll back completed successfully.

How can I deploy the package, why is it failing?

Answer (score 1):

Db2 supports the compilation / creation of PL/SQL packages when the [database is set up for Oracle compatibility](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053607.html):

```
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA
db2stop
db2start
```

Bit 12 in the [DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html) enables PL/SQL compilation.